# Exporting an array to a text file using multiple cores (parallel computation)

Tags: c++, file, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I've written a code that that exports a 2D array and writes it to a text file. The program works perfectly when using one core (1 processor/ 1 thread/ 1 CPU). However, when using multiple cores, the data from the last core overwrites the file. Which leads me to have only part of the array that I need.

I've turned this around by writing n text files for n cores. Below is the code that utilizes 3 cores and creates 3 text files:

```
void expvector(){

    if(mype == 0){
        int ta, tb;
        ofstream tpfile;
        tpfile.open("testpressup0.txt");
        for(tb=0;tb<80;tb++)
        for(ta=0;ta<160;ta++)
                tpfile << pressure[ta][tb] << "\n";
        tpfile.close();
    }
            
        if(mype == 1){
        int ta1, tb1;
        ofstream tpfile1;
        tpfile1.open("testpressup1.txt");
        for(tb1=0;tb1<80;tb1++)
        for(ta1=0;ta1<160;ta1++)
                tpfile1 << pressure[ta1][tb1] << "\n";
        tpfile1.close();
    }

        if(mype == 2){
        int ta2, tb2;
        ofstream tpfile2;
        tpfile2.open("testpressup2.txt");
        for(tb2=0;tb2<80;tb2++)
        for(ta2=0;ta2<160;ta2++)
                tpfile2 << pressure[ta2][tb2] << "\n";
        tpfile2.close();
    }

}
```

mype gives the rank of the current processor and I use OpenMPI/MPI to use multiple processors/parallel process.

While creating and writing in multiple text files temporarily fixes the problem, I'd like to create just one file and export/write the data in a way that the the contents does not get over written. I will be running this code using a HPC in a few weeks and creating 40+ text files in the hope of post processing right doesn't make sense.

I'm not really sure how to go about this and given the time crunch I'm in, any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks (:

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider providing a Minimal, Reproducible Example. I don't see how your code uses multiple threads.

Comment: If you knew the size of each chunk ahead of time you could use `pwrite`, but in a text format that's unlikely. But since you're I/O bouind there's no point in using multiple CPUs.

Comment: Note that MPI has MPI-I/O which supports writing files from multiple MPI processes. However, this will be in practice faster only if there is a support from parallel file system (such as Lustre).

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin this is just a snippet that exports data in a large DNS code. I'm not sure if this helps (sorry I'm a noob) but i employ multiple threads using mpiexec

Comment: @o11c  want to export the contents of the array to a binary file. Would that work then? Can you please tell me what you suggest I do otherwise?

Comment: @thermocoder if the file is binary, you can likely say: thread 1 has 100 items, each 8 bytes in size, so thread 2 starts with an offset of 800 passed to `pwrite`. That said, I'm still not convinced that doing I/O on multiple CPUs will ever be useful, since (even NVMe) disks are extremely slow compared to CPUs. Either way, you'll certainly want to avoid `<iostream>`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks a ton! Looking at other similar answers online, I believe MPI I/O is hard to implement. Is there a way I can send all the data to one processor (without it being over written) and then export it?

Comment: @thermocoder It's not hard at all. You just need to know the offset for each process, which, if you know the amount of process-written data, can be easily calculated by prefix sum (see `MPI_Scan` or `MPI_Exscan`). Anyway, of course that you can send all data to a single process and write from it to a file as well. Just it is not a scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a single file is that each process has an independent file pointer, so you get collisions left and right. Use MPI I/O to open a single file. This may get you started: [https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-io.html](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-io.html)

Comment: Thanks you so much!